# I want to install oracle-java8 on Ubuntu:

Tags: xubuntu, java, jdk

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you added the repository ? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` and refreshed package database `sudo apt update` before trying to install ?

Comment: @SorenA This repository has been discontinued

Comment: Yes,i have added and also refreshed package database.

Comment: @Kulfy,I also read that this repository has been discontinued.but will you please tell me then how to install it,i need this for my project.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html)

Comment: You need to download it from oracle's site and follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/816190)

Answer (score 0):

I still use java version 8 and follow these steps to install via command line whenever I nuke an OS

add the discontinued repository, it will automatically  install the repository for the newer version but will not prevent you from installing previous versions of java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update
```

install java version 8 default, jre or jdk

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
# or
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
# or
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

verify your version of java

```
java -version
```

set your environment variables

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle recently changed the licensing for their JDK/JRE to require everybody to have a subscription to get newer releases than 8u201. You can either switch to another JDK or buy the subscription and download/install the new oracle-jdk package manually.

Most software should run fine with openjdk-8-* - this might therefore be a worthwhile first test.